# Android - Run a service in background to get my location and show notification if is close to a determinate location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, service, background-process

I'm trying to make a app with Google Maps API. My app is OK, getting my location and in SetOnMyLocationChangeListener i put to show me a alert if is close to my destination.
Now i need run this app in background, to when the user's location is close to destination, show a notification to alert him. Even if the app isn't open.

I searched for Service class but i don't understand how it work.

Answer (score 4):

You have to do the following steps:

**Edit: use LocationManager**

Create a class which extends Service. In the onStart method, setup the LocationManager and read the destination from the intent extras. You need to pass the destination location with the intent.

You need to add your service to the manifest:

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

From any of your Activities start the Service using an Intent. For example like this

**Edit: Add destination to intent**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("destination", destination);
startService(intent);
```

The following is an example Service which creates a notification for each location update and shows the distance to a destination. You can adapt it to your needs.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyService extends Service {

    private Location mDestination;

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            float distance = mDestination.distanceTo(location);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyService.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle("Distance")
                            .setContentText(Float.toString(distance));
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("MyService", "onStart: " + intent);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        mDestination = intent.getParcelableExtra("destination");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return START_NOT_STICKY;
            }
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                locationListener);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. With this code, the service will start when the app is open or when the smartphone is started?

Comment: The service is started when you call startService(...) from one of your activites. Do you want it to start when the phone is starting?

Comment: I tried to implement this code but the GoogleApiClient cant connect. Error:
getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled

Comment: Are you running your app on a mobile phone or an emulator. Does the phone or emaulator have Google Services installed? How did you get location updates before? Did you use LocationManager or the FusedLocationApi as in my example? I could rewrite the example to use LocationManager so you don't need the GoogleApiClient.

Comment: I'm running in a device. With the app open, i don't using GoogleAPIClient to check my location, i get the LatLng coordinate and measuring the distance with distancebetween, so i want to make the same in the service, to obtain my actual coordinate i use the GoogleMaps.setOnMyLocationChangeListener. and calculate the distance. how i do in service and how to implement to only execute service if the app is closed.

Comment: I made a few modifications to the service. The LocationManager should work. You need to pass the destination with the intent when you start the service. The LocationManager uses the network provider cause I tried it indoors. Switch to GPS provider if you need more accurate readings. This service runs as long as your app is in the foreground and background. When your app is killed the service will restart. The problem is, when it gets restarted the intent is null. To make your service work even when your app is killed you need to persist your destination and read it back when the service starts

Comment: How i detected if my app is closed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95599/discussion-between-emanuel-seidinger-and-felipersn).